# Переделать скрипт под три формы

Tags: ajax, javascript

Есть скрипт. 
Работает с двумя формами. Никак не могу переписать его под работу с тремя формами.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Display form from link inside a popup
    $('#pop_login, #pop_signup').live('click', function (e) {
        formToFadeOut = $('form#register');
        formtoFadeIn = $('form#login');
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'pop_signup') {
            formToFadeOut = $('form#login');
            formtoFadeIn = $('form#register');

        }

        formToFadeOut.fadeOut(500, function () {
            formtoFadeIn.fadeIn();
        })

        return false;
    });

    // Show the login/signup popup on click
    $('#show_login, #show_signup).on('click', function (e) {
        $('body').prepend('<div class="login_overlay"></div>');
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'show_login') 
            $('form#login').fadeIn(500);
        else
            $('form#recover').fadeIn(500);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Perform AJAX login/register on form submit
    $('form#login, form#register').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!$(this).valid()) return false;
        $('p.status', this).show().text(ajax_auth_object.loadingmessage);
        action = 'ajaxlogin';
        username =  $('form#login #username').val();
        password = $('form#login #password').val();
        email = '';
        security = $('form#login #security').val();
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'register') {
            action = 'ajaxregister';
            username = $('#signonname').val();
            email = $('#email').val();
            security = $('#signonsecurity').val();  
        }

        ctrl = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_auth_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': action,
                'username': username,
                'password': password,
                'email': email,
                'security': security
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('p.status', ctrl).text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true) {
                    document.location.href = ajax_auth_object.redirecturl;
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Client side form validation
    if (jQuery("#register").length) 
        jQuery("#register").validate();
    else if (jQuery("#login").length) 
        jQuery("#login").validate();
});
```

Кто подскажет, как сделать? *)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас с кодом какая-то ж*па) пропущены кавычки, используется избыточный селектор (вместо "form#login" пишем просто "#login"), используется jQuery() вместо $(), используется устаревший метод .live() вместо .on().
Вам надо полностью переписать код

Comment: Потратил ночь на чтение и пришел к такому же выводу =)